# How can I add a header to an AWS S3 presigned URL in Go?

Tags: go, amazon-s3, pre-signed-url, aws-sdk-go

I'm uploading a file to an AWS S3 bucket using a presigned URL. This works fine, but if I try to add a [x-amz-tagging](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/API_PutObject.html#API_PutObject_RequestSyntax) header I get the error "There were headers present in the request which were not signed".

The backend generating the presigned URL is written in Go:

```
// Upload generates a new URL where a file can be uploaded
func (s *S3) Upload(key string, c Config) (string, error) {
    req, _ := s.client.PutObjectRequest(&s3.PutObjectInput{
        Bucket: aws.String(s.bucketName),
        Key:    aws.String(key),
    })

    return req.Presign(c.ExpiresIn)
}
```

The answer to [S3 presigned upload url error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51376585/s3-presigned-upload-url-error) suggests that we need to declare the header as part of the presigned URL. How can I add a header declaration to this? The examples given on [Creating Pre-Signed URLs for Amazon S3 Buckets](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-go/v1/developer-guide/s3-example-presigned-urls.html) don't cover this.

Comment: URLs don't have headers.

Answer (score 0):

If i remember correctly, you can add metadata like this:

```
  'Bucket': 'bucket',
  'Key': 'signed.json',
  'Metadata': {
    'x-amz-tagging': 'whatever'
  },
```

So it'll look something like this:

```
// Upload generates a new URL where a file can be uploaded
func (s *S3) Upload(key string, c Config) (string, error) {
    req, _ := s.client.PutObjectRequest(&s3.PutObjectInput{
        Bucket: aws.String(s.bucketName),
        Key:    aws.String(key),
        Body: {
                'x-amz-tagging': 'whatever'
       },
    })

    return req.Presign(c.ExpiresIn)
}
```

I wrote this on the fly, so it might not work and need a bit of tweaking. Refer to the docs - but it should look like this. Test it out and let me know.

Read more here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-go/api/service/s3/#PutObjectInput

Comment: I had a look at that documentation but I thought it would use "Tagging" rather than "Metadata". You've used "Body" in your code though.

I also wanted not to declare the value of "x-amz-tagging" so can "whatever" be "*"?

Answer (score -1):

The presigned URL request just needs the tags under the Tagging field. When you use this URL to make a request, that's when you pass the header with "x-amz-tagging" as the key and the tags (e.g., "temp=true&public=yes").

Below is an example of uploading an image with tags (through the headers) using a presigned url that was also requested with tags (with Tagging).

```
  const uploadImage = async (filepath, presignedURL) => {
    const headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('x-amz-tagging', 'temp=true&public=yes');
    const response = await fetch(filepath);
    const blob = await response.blob();
    return await fetch(
      presignedURL,
      {
        method: 'PUT',
        body: blob,
        headers,
      },
    );
};
```

Comment: That's not answering my question.

Comment: I think I jumped the gun. It looks like you just need to add the Tagging key and an aws.String in your PutObjectInput and that will add the headers to your request for you. My answer then would be the next step to upload (in whatever language). The links you reference talk about appending headers after you already have the url from your request so those were the headers I thought you meant (but which you will still need to add).